# Viewing log file after appveyor script fails

Tags: build-error, appveyor

I am trying to diagnose an error during the build of a project with appveyor. This same project is also built with travis-ci, without any problems. I assume it is windows related.

The script produces some log files, but I have no clue on how these can be viewed after appveyor is done trying to build.

As a specific example: See [the log of this build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/hanjoosten/ampersand/build/build.1337-development). At line 11706 it says:

> Logs have been written to: C:\stack.stack-work\logs\yaml-0.8.28.log

How can I view the contents of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [push this file as artifact](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/#pushing-artifacts-from-scripts) at `on_finish` stage, or simple [RDP](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/) to the build worker and explore it interactively.

Side note: you can also try to debug your build in RDP, but note that environment variables from the build session are not available in the RDP session, so you need to re-create all or part of them.